# graysclae to original automatic image transition in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  /* Transition for Webkit browsers*/
}
img.grayscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<img class="grayscale" src="https://62e528761d0685343e1c-f3d1b99a743ffa4142d9d7f1978d9686.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/files/93616/area14mp/image-20150902-6700-t2axrz.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
```

How to make this conversion from grayscale to original image automatically & with hovering

Comment: what you mean of `automatically` if I understand right you need css3 animation. can you explain more about automatically?

Comment: currently it is working on hover as you can see there, but I want to make it like changing from grayscale to original color automatically means without hovering also it need to change the color

Comment: Ok so you need `css3` animation. going to write your answer.

Comment: You got answer, no need I post my answer too, but here is my example that works automatically and hover also. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLfuu8mx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[css3 animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation)** for that

```css
@keyframes ani {
  0%, 100% {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray;
    /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    /* Transition for Webkit browsers*/
  }
  50% {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
}
.grayscale {
  animation: ani 5s infinite;
}
.grayscale:hover {
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="grayscale" src="https://62e528761d0685343e1c-f3d1b99a743ffa4142d9d7f1978d9686.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/files/93616/area14mp/image-20150902-6700-t2axrz.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
```

You can get more examples here : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Comment: i need automatically and hover both